# REACT- Making 2 different dynamic displays depending on a selection checkboxes ( everything is on the same page now)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hook-form

depending on the selection of my user `Change the type` or `Choose the comments` (he can select only one choice), there will be a different display, but my code displayed both options in the same page.

So, in the begining there are only 2 checkboxes `Change the type` or `Choose the comments` then depending on the selection the display appears

```
 export default function App(){
  ...
  return (
    <>
     {/* Step 1- 2 checkboxes are displayed */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)} />
        <span className="text-md p-1 font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Change the type{" "}
        </span>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} />
        <span className="text-md p-1 font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Choose the comments{" "}
        </span>
      </form>
      
      {/*Step 2 - if setType ==true then display */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={menu}
          placeholder="Menu"
          onChange={(e) => setMenu(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="text-md font-bold  text-gray-500 flex flex-wrap gap-x-2 ">
          Type : <CustomDropdown options={LOCATION} isMulti={false} />
        </div>
        <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Location:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={location}
          placeholder="Location"
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>

      {/*Step 2 - if setComment ==true (selected) then display */}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Comments />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={menu}
          placeholder="Menu"
          onChange={(e) => setMenu(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="text-md font-bold  text-gray-500 flex flex-wrap gap-x-2 ">
          Type : <CustomDropdown options={LOCATION} isMulti={false} />
        </div>
        <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Location:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={location}
          placeholder="Location"
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/first-page-with-dynamic-field-e3ofjj?file=/src/App.js:0-3086)

Here a picture to get the idea :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood better thanks to the picture you added, here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/first-page-with-dynamic-field-forked-vpxyhu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, I think we didn't understant each other, I've edited the issue by adding a picture to get the idea